# how to display my own custome message in the top of admin page

Tags: django

want to display my own custom message and link in the top of `localhost/admin/module/field` before the `select fields to change` page. I tried with link_display that for displaying each instance obj itself, and i don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `change_list.html` template for your app, see the [documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)

Money quote for your problem:

> For example, if we wanted to add a tool to the change list view for
>   all the models in an app named my_app, we would copy
>   contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html to the
>   templates/admin/my_app/ directory of our project, and make any
>   necessary changes.